# Skyscreaper sheaf, Ext and Hom.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $C$ be a reduced, projective curve and denote  by $\mathbb{C}_x$ the skyscreaper sheaf of lenght one supported at $x$. Is there an easy way to compute

$Hom(\mathbb{C}_x,\mathbb{C}_y$), $Ext^1(\mathbb{C}_x,\mathbb{C}_y)$ and $Hom(\mathbb{C}_x,V)$, where $V$ is a vector bundle over $C$ and $y\in C$?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the skyscraper sheaf should come from restriction and extension to the point $\{x\} \to C$. Using adjunctions and derived functors you should be able to reduce computations on a point, which are very easy (just vector spaces!)

Comment: I would guess that the first two are zero. However what happens to the third one?

Comment: I would say it is $V_x$, the stalk at that point (by pulling back to the point and using $Hom(\mathbb{C}, U) \simeq U$ for any vector space $U$

Comment: The first two zero if $x \ne y$, and one dimensional if $x = y$. The third is zero (since a vector bundle is torsion free).

Comment: @sasha ext is one dimensional only if $x$ is a smooth point in general.

Comment: @Mohan. Sure, I had the smooth case in mind. In general $Ext^1$ is the tangent space to the curve at the point.